# javascript code not displaying data from xml file

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm reading an xml file with javascript and if the user clicks on the 'forgot password' button, a modal shows up, where there is another button called 'get my password'. If the user clicks on this button, it's supposed to show the users' password based on his email id in the xml file, but my function is not working for some reason.
my html form:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="login">
  <h1 class="login-heading">Please login.</h1>
<form method="post" action="login.php">
<input id='email1' type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Adress" required="required" class="input-txt" onchange="checkuser();"  /> &nbsp;
        <input id='pass1' type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" class="input-txt" />
        
        <input type"button" name="forgot" class="btn" data-target="#pwdModal" data-toggle="modal" value="Forgot password?">
<div id="pwdModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h1 >Forgot My Password?</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="text-center">
                          
                          <p>If you have forgotten your password, simply click on the button below to fetch your password from the server!</p>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <fieldset>
                                    
                                    <div id="forgot">
             <input type="button" class="btn" value="Get my password" tabindex="2" onclick="forgotten();"><br> <br>
                         <p id="pass" style="border-style:dotted;border-color:coral; border-radius:5px;"></p>
</div>   
          </fieldset>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="col-md-12">
          <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
          </div>    
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn" name="ok" id="b1" >Sign in </button> <br><br></form>
<script>
             
//checking if the email exists in the server xml or not
var first_email = document.getElementById("email1");
var forgotten_pass='';

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

//creating an array of the existing emails
request.open("GET", "storedata.xml", false);
request.send();

var xml = request.responseXML;
var users = xml.getElementsByTagName("data");
const existingEmails = [];

for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    const emailTag = users[i].getElementsByTagName("email2");
    const email = emailTag[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    existingEmails.push(email);
}

function checkuser() {
 if(existingEmails.includes(first_email.value)) {
      email1.setCustomValidity('');
 }
 else {
 email1.setCustomValidity('Sorry but this email address doesnt exist in the server.');
 }
}

//grabbing the forgotten password 
function forgotten {
for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (first_email == users[i].getElementsByTagName("email2") {
    forgotten_pass= users[i].getElementsByTagName("pass2");
    }
    
} document.getElementById("pass").innerHTML=forgotten_pass;
}
</script>        
 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using `false` for async is deprecated (because it is a horrible practice) and should never be used. Use an event listener to access and process the data. You should be seeing deprecation warnings in browser dev tools console

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you tried async?

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open("GET", "storedata.xml", true);

request.onreadystatechange=function(){

 if((this.readyState==4)&&(this.status==200)){

   var xml = request.responseXML;

   // etc etc etc

 }

};

request.send();
```

Comment: I did try like this,  `function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
 for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (first_email == users[i].getElementsByTagName("email2") {
 forgotten_pass= users[i].getElementsByTagName("pass2");
 }
 
    }
  }document.getElementById("pass").innerHTML=forgotten_pass;
  ;
  xhttp.open("GET", "storedata.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
}` but it's still not working, I am new to this, can you please clarify how it's supposed to be done?

Comment: I think how I'm getting the variable forgotten_pass is the issue, I'd be really grateful if you could help me out

Comment: Change:  var xml = request.responseXML;  to var xml = this.responseXML;

Comment: Use... alert(this.responseText);  to TEST before the loops.

Comment: it's not working, should I make two separate scripts and transfer the forgotten function right below the modal where I'm calling the function?

Answer (score 0):

If there's an error this version will tell you... just set the URL and test it.

```
var X=new XMLHttpRequest(); X.open('GET',URL,true); X.responseType='text';

X.onreadystatechange=function(){

 if(X.readyState==4){

  if(X.status==200){

    alert(X.responseText); // Observe the text, is it empty?

  } else {alert(X.statusText);}  // observe the error

 }

};

X.send();
```

Comment: It's not even running then! Put it in a function and call it like this... <body onload="MyFunc();"> Look, maybe this project is too much for you! :)

Comment: `var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
             xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
             if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
             myFunction(this);
             }
             };
             xhttp.open("GET", "storedata.xml", true);
             xhttp.send();`

Comment: `function myFunction(xml) {
             var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    //need to create a loop to loop through the data tags in the xml file
             var data_tag = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('data')[i];
             var email_tag = data_tag.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var pass_tag= data_tag.childNodes[3].nodeValue;
             }`

Comment: this is what I wrote, can you just help me figure out how to create a loop to loop through all the data tags in the xml file please?